# Specific phone number regex

Tags: regex

I need a pattern to validate a phone number but I don't know regex very well.

What I need is that only this 2 patterns be accepted:

(99) 99999-9999

(99) 9999-9999

Got this one:

```
/\(?([0-9]{2})\)?([ ]?)([0-9]{4})\2([0-9]{4})/
```

But not worked as expected.

Comment: A more permissive way is to remove likely additional characters `tel = tel.replace(/[\(\)\s-]/g, "");` then test length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regular expression should be of use to you;

```
/^\([0-9]{2}\)[ ][0-9]{4,5}\-[0-9]{4}$/
```

http://regex101.com/r/yQ2iV5/2

[image: Graphical version]